# Flutter: Binding is already initialized to AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding

Tags: flutter

I have a couple simple tests implemented in my app.
They execute and pass when I run the test on MacOS
But it fails like bellow when I run it on Linux.

```
$ sip test --recursive --no-version-check --test-randomize-ordering-seed random --bail

✓ Optimizing test files (12ms)
Running (dart) tests in apps/mobile/packages/data
Shuffling test order with --test-randomize-ordering-seed=3299446048
00:00 +6: All tests passed!
Finished in 1.3s

Running (flutter) tests in apps/mobile/packages/ui
Shuffling test order with --test-randomize-ordering-seed=720132089
00:01 +0 -1: loading /home/user/myapp/apps/mobile/packages/ui/test/.test_optimizer.dart [E]
  Failed to load "/home/user/myapp/apps/mobile/packages/ui/test/.test_optimizer.dart": 'package:flutter/src/foundation/binding.dart': Failed assertion: line 153 pos 12: '_debugInitializedType == null': Binding is already initialized to AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding
  dart:core                                                _AssertionError._throwNew
  package:flutter/src/foundation/binding.dart 153:12       new BindingBase
  package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart                    new _TestWidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&SchedulerBinding
  package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart                    new _TestWidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&SchedulerBinding&ServicesBinding
  package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart                    new _TestWidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&SchedulerBinding&ServicesBinding&GestureBinding
  package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart                    new _TestWidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&SchedulerBinding&ServicesBinding&GestureBinding&SemanticsBinding
  package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart                    new _TestWidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&SchedulerBinding&ServicesBinding&GestureBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding
  package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart                    new _TestWidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&SchedulerBinding&ServicesBinding&GestureBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding&PaintingBinding
  package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart                    new _TestWidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&SchedulerBinding&ServicesBinding&GestureBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding&PaintingBinding&WidgetsBinding
  package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart                    new _TestWidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&SchedulerBinding&ServicesBinding&GestureBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding&PaintingBinding&WidgetsBinding&TestDefaultBinaryMessengerBinding
  package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart                    new TestWidgetsFlutterBinding
  package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart                    new LiveTestWidgetsFlutterBinding
  package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart 1688:7             LiveTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized
  test/lib/screens/login/login_screen_test.dart 41:33  main
  test/.test_optimizer.dart 9:66                           main.<fn>
  package:test_api                                         Declarer.group
  package:flutter_test/src/test_compat.dart 189:13         group
  test/.test_optimizer.dart 9:3                            main
```

As you can see on the stacktrace, on my test I'm calling

```
...
void main() {
  LiveTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  ...
}
```

`AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding` is not called anywhere in my code.
My assumption is that something inside flutter test structure is setting this binding.

Flutter Doctor on Linux:

```
➜ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.9, on Arch Linux 6.7.4-arch1-1, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
[✓] Android Studio (version 2023.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] Network resources

• No issues found!
```

Flutter Doctor on MacOS

```
➜ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.9, on macOS 13.6.5 22G621 darwin-x64, locale en-BR)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.2)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2023.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.87.2)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] Network resources

• No issues found!
```

What is different on linux env that the binding is set and on macos it is not?